# É errado deixar regra de negócio nos controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, design-pattern

Eu vejo em vários exemplo de código isso, e até mesmo no projeto "padrão" que se cria no visual studio, eles deixam uma boa parte da regra no controller

É errado? Quando usar isso? Qual a vantagem e desvantagem?

Comment: Boa, eu nunca soube ao certo até que ponto uma regra seria de uma Controller ou de um Model (não só em .NET)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende.

Acho melhor categorizar por tipo de regra pra ficar mais claro.

### Validações de dados

Sim, é errado. Validação de dados é uma característica do tipo de dado, portanto, de responsabilidade do *Model*.

### Verificação de existência de registro referenciado

Não. É função do *Controller* verificar se o registro de outra tabela realmente existe antes de fazer qualquer atribuição. A responsabilidade do Controller é harmonizar os dados entre *Models* e também entre a camada de apresentação.

### Auditoria de dados (log)

Depende. Se o tipo de dados a ser auditado segue um padrão de formato e dados, o melhor é usar uma biblioteca (como as que trabalham com aspectos) que interceptam o dado, ou então um `ActionFilter`.

Caso contrário, não há problemas em usar isso no Controller, desde que seu Controller tenha um suporte adequado a transações.

### Montar *Views*

Sim, **muito** errado. O *Controller* deve apenas fornecer os dados para as *Views*. Nunca montar HTML, por exemplo.

Isto não se aplica caso o resultado devolvido por um *Controller* seja um arquivo (por exemplo, uma imagem ou um PDF), ou algum formato de dados padronizado (um JSON, um XML, e assim por diante).

Há uma ressalva sobre PDFs. Existe um pacote chamado [RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2) que monta PDFs a nível de *View*. Este pacote é da minha autoria, então qualquer dúvida ou se quiser reportar bugs, pode me contatar através dos meios disponíveis aqui no site (menção, chat, etc.).

---

## Vantagens

- Simples e transparente. A regra que se vê é a regra executada de fato;
- Rápido pra desenvolver;
- Pode abarcar um único escopo transacional, diferentemente dos *Services*, cuja isolabilidade exige chamar vários repositórios, aumentando desnecessariamente o código.

## Desvantagens

- Se o seu sistema é grande, as regras de cada método do *Controller* podem ficar enormes se as responsabilidades não forem bem segmentadas. Por exemplo, um método que executa múltiplas regras de negócio, insere em log, etc.;
- Se um grande conjunto de regras precisa ser executado em vários *Controllers*, usar uma abordagem dessa pode deixar o código deveras repetitivo (pessoalmente falando, apenas para estes casos vejo o uso de uma camada de serviços como algo positivo).

Comment: Pois é Cigano, como falei, vi uma boa parte da regra em controllers, há também os que criam classes "Service"(O que eu acho complicado em algumas partes) e nos controllers são muito fácil de regenciar e até mesmo aplicar DI para os reposiroty

Comment: Não vejo necessidade da camada de `Service`, sendo que o `Controller` absorve bem esta função.

Comment: E quando precisa compartilhar certas regras entre entidades?

Comment: Bom, minha opinião: abandone de vez essa ideia de usar Service, porque esse design está atrapalhando a funcionalidade dos componentes da aplicação.

Answer (score 5):

De preferência evite fazer isso, claro que pode haver exceções.

Existem várias argumentações do por quê, se você tiver uma mesma regra que será utilizada por outro *controller*? Você irá duplicar? Então mover para uma outra classe que muitas vezes será um Service vai te facilitar o reuso.

Você está ferindo o princípio de responsabilidade exclusiva do [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Basicamente você estará deixando seu controller fazer mais coisas do que ele deveria fazer.

Mas pra não parecer inflexível demais, se você estiver apenas fazendo uma agenda telefônica isso pode não ser um problema, mas quando sua agenda telefônica começar a crescer é hora de seguir boas práticas que vão te evitar dores de cabeças e códigos macarrônicos.

Comment: Apenas opinativamente, discordo que o formato específico do ASP.NET MVC vá contra o SOLID, considerando que o projeto utilize um bom Framework de abstração de dados, como o Entity Framework. Se a lógica precisa ser repetida em mais de um *Controller*, significa que o projeto em si é falho, pois há dois *Controllers* realizando a mesma ação, o que não justifica nem a nível de rotas (já que é possível definir vários conjuntos de rotas). Ainda em tempo, a abordagem sobre serviço e repositório é prolixa e o ganho é pequeno em Design.

Comment: Eu não disse que o formato do ASP.NET MVC vá contra o SOLID, se o entendimento da resposta foi esse então não fui claro. Eu disse que colocar regras de negócios na sua camada de controller você estará ferindo alguns princípios do SOLID dentre eles o princípio de responsabilidade exclusiva.